# How to make the language of the subscriptions be the currently language in Simplenews

Tags: i18n-l10n, emails, configuration

I'm implementing simplenews on a Drupal 8 Website, and I currently came across a problem with the anonymous user subscriptions to the newsletters.

According to the documentation of simplenews, when someone subscribe anonymously to a Newsletter, the preferred language would be the interface language of the page, but the language setted to the subscriber is always being the default language of the website, I tried many configurations about language and have no success.

So, that is the problem, I want that when someone subscribe to the newsletter, the language setted for the subscriber be the interface language of the page, please tell if anybody knows a solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but do you have interface language negotiation configured? What are the settings you selected and in what order?

Comment: Yep, I have, configured by URL prefix and selected language, I ended up modifiyng a line in the code, to get the interface language. Not the best solution, but worked